# How to register DOMContentLoaded to native HTML element in Angular 5 template?

Tags: angular

So, I have Iframe as part of the template of a component.

How can I subscribe to `DOMContentLoaded` event?

Neither will work:
`(domcontentloaded)`
`(DOMContentLoaded)`

Comment: what about ngAfterContentInit() lifecylce hook?

Comment: I could not find any info on when is that hook triggered in relation to native DOM events. Is that really `DOMContentLoaded`? Or is it `onLoad`? If you have such info please post it as an answer. Thx.